# Failed to get Response from functions in parse migration

Tags: parse-platform

i have tried to get response from functions in parse migration with the following url https://XXXXX/parse/functions/functionname
but i am getting the response like this
{
  "code": 141,
  "error": "Invalid function."
}

but it is perfectly working for classes/classname

can any body help me?

Answer (score 0):

it is completely the problem of Path which specified for main.js in Index.js file.
"cloud: path.join(__dirname, '/cloud/main.js')"like this we have to give path for main.js and one more problem is version compatibility of node modules which you have used in your main.js file.Make sure about that and install all the require modules like twilio,mailgun,etc...